# Normed Division Algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra

It is a well known result that the only normed associative division algebras over $\mathbb R$, up to isomorphism, are $\mathbb{R}$, $\mathbb{C}$, and $\mathbb{H}.$ However, if non-associativity is allowed, then the octonions are a normed division algebra.

This is an open ended question, but I am interested in other conditions that can be relaxed. For example, the split complex numbers form a division algebra; however, they do not have a positive-definite norm, rather, they have a modulus.

The dual numbers also have division within the algebra.

Are there some other examples of algebras which are “almost” normed division algebras?

Comment: recommend Lam, *Introduction to Quadratic Forms over Fields*, https://bookstore.ams.org/view?ProductCode=GSM/67

Comment: $\Bbb{R}[x]/(x^2-1)$ is of course not a division algebra

Comment: "division algebra" is a narrow term. This expression does not mean that there is operation of division, rather it means that we can divide by any element except zero. In split-complex and dual numbers definitely there is division but they are not "division algebras" because there are non-zero elements by which we cannot divide (the result goes to infinity).